# How to Stop Django Thread

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a website that uses Jquery and Python.

I have an Ajax Request that performs a python function.  Inside the Python Function there is an interface with Linux that executes a C++ Library.

The problem I am having is when I create two requests to execute this C++ Library from AJAX via Python.  The C++ Task could take upto 2 minutes to load.  This is fine however when I navigate away from the current page since the previous task has technically not completed Django will not load me a new page.

Is there any way I can determaine if the page is navigating away and if so then invoke python to stop its function so I can have some responsiveness.

One way I have thought of is threading however when I perform this approach if i Navigate away while a thread is still executing I can see from the debugger that it returns data even if I am not on the page that called the request.

So does anyone have any ideas how I can get python to kill all threads upon navigation away from its current page.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need an asynchronous execution for your "blocking" C++ Lib. There are several approaches for this kind of problems but IMO threading is deferentially the wrong one...

One approach is to use an asynchronous web server like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpserver.html) to handle asynchronous requests. The other (and the one I like more) is to use [Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html).